# Selecting rows and ordering the result in R

Tags: sorting, r, dataframe

The seemingly trivial task of selecting rows in a data frame and then ordering them is eluding me, and driving me crazy at the same time. For example, lets have a trivial data frame:

```
country = c("US", "US", "CA", "US")
company = c("Apple", "Google", "RIM", "MS")
vals = c(100, 70, 50, 90)
df <- data.frame(country, company, vals)
```

Lets order it by vals

```
> df[order(vals),]
  country company vals
3      CA     RIM   50
2      US  Google   70
4      US      MS   90
1      US   Apple  100
```

Works perfectly. Lets now try to select only US companies, and order there values. We get some bogus result.

```
> df[country=="US", ][order(vals),]
    country company vals
4       US      MS   90
2       US  Google   70
NA    <NA>    <NA>   NA
1       US   Apple  100
```

Lets order, and then select. Again, a bogus result

```
> df[order(vals),][country=="US", ]
  country company vals
3      CA     RIM   50
2      US  Google   70
1      US   Apple  100
```

How do I get a data frame, which only includes US companies, and is sorted by val?

Comment: Remove the variables used to create `df` before you start doing this, as these will get found not the ones in `df`. This doesn't solve the problem, but will help...

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/sort.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure you can do this via a set of subsetting calls to `[`, as you need to refer to ordered or reduced data frame at the second subsetting call. One way is to order the data and supply this to `subset()` to choose rows from this *ordered* data frame:

```
> with(df, subset(df[order(vals),], subset = country == "US"))
  country company vals
2      US  Google   70
4      US      MS   90
1      US   Apple  100
```

Comment: +1 I always prefer the subset approach. Slight simplification -- you don't need to say `subset = ` inside the `subset()` call.

Comment: I'm always wary of positional matching, especially when demonstrating code or writing reproducible code for my work, because if I, in the above, write `subset = FOO`, I obviously meant to use `subset` and not some other argument. So you're right, I don't *need* to spell this out, but I find it is safer to do so, just in case.

Answer (score 6):

I always found it odd that base R didn't have a convenience for reordering a data frame like it does for subsetting.  So I wrote my own:

```
library(plyr)
arrange(subset(df, country == "US"), vals)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> df[df$country=="US",][order(df[df$country=="US","vals"]),]
  country company vals
2      US  Google   70
4      US      MS   90
1      US   Apple  100
```

I think it's a good habit to remove the original variables and just work with the dataframe (so df$country instead of country).

Comment: That works, but you are, in effect, doing the `country=="US"` subsetting twice. It would be easier to do the two steps separately, especially if the compute cost of `country=="US"` is high on the the real data, e.g.: `tmp <- df[order(df$vals), ]` followed by `tmp[tmp$country == "US",]`. Replace `tmp` with `df` if the reordering step is not harmful.

Comment: I agree, and I had first written your exact two-liner.  For some reason though I decided to combine the steps.  I like your solution better.